# Backbone: Refresh the current route

Tags: backbone.js

I noticed that the backbone router's navigate method won't reload the current path.

For example the current route is `/view1` and you call `router.navigate('view1',{trigger:true});`. It won't activate the route event again.

Here's the code I test:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing123</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #box{
            width:400px;
            height:400px;
            background-color:red;
        }       
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id='view1'>view1</button>
    <button id='view2'>view2</button>
    <br/>
    <div id='box'>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer>
        var SystemRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

          routes: {
            "view1":"view1",
            "view2":"view2"
          },

          view1: function() {
            console.log('view1');
          },

          view2: function() {
            console.log('view2');
          }

        });

        var sys = new SystemRouter();
        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/test/routing.html#/"});
        sys.navigate('view1');

        $('#view1').click(function(){
            sys.navigate('view1',{trigger:true});
        });

        $('#view2').click(function(){
           sys.navigate('view2',{trigger:true});
        }); 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code above will load `/view1` path, which prints out 'view1'. But if you try to click the button to navigate to `/view1` path, it will be ignored.

My question is: How do I call the route event if it is the same as the current path?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are several things that would accomplish this. If you anticipate navigating to a route that is already in the url, then first check the current route fragment with `Backbone.history.fragment` and see if it is the same as the route you want to activate. If so, then you can do any of the following:

1. You could just call the route method directly: `sys.view1();`
2. You could set the fragment to another dead route, then back to the route you want.

   `sys.navigate('someDeadRoute');
   sys.navigate('view1',{trigger: true});`
3. You could stop and restart the router:

   `Backbone.history.stop(); 
   Backbone.history.start()`

   This would pickup the route again and run it.

I think I would go with #1.

Comment: I'd already tried option 1 before I can across this solution, but when I tried to go back, the routes update but the view does not. Did you experience this issue?

Answer (score 29):

Rather than starting & stopping Backbone's history, you can call `Backbone.history.loadUrl`.

To refresh the current page:

`Backbone.history.loadUrl(Backbone.history.fragment);`

Or as a link handler:

```
// `Backbone.history.navigate` is sufficient for all Routers and will trigger the
// correct events. The Router's internal `navigate` method calls this anyways.
var ret = Backbone.history.navigate(href, true);

// Typically Backbone's history/router will do nothing when trying to load the same URL.
// But since we want it to re-fire the same route, we can detect 
// when Backbone.history.navigate did nothing, and force the route.
if (ret === undefined) {
    Backbone.history.loadUrl(href);
}
```

Comment: this seems to work for me, and you don't lose state this way, whereas you do lose state by stopping and starting the history?