# Backbone render method called but different view displaying on back button press

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, back-button, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I have a backbone.js application, and I'm running into a situation where I need to reload a url. In other words, the user is on a current url, and I need to reload the page. To do so, I'm using the solution from this post: [Backbone: Refresh the same route path for twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526752/backbone-refresh-the-same-route-path-for-twice). So if my route looks like this:

```
"patrons/new(/)":"newPatron",
```

then I reload the page by calling

```
router.newPatron();
```

This all works great. The problem is when I hit the back button. The url will change and go back through the history, but the view doesn't change. On each back button click, the correct render methods are getting called.

So the url and render methods are corresponding to the backbutton changes, but the view is not changing correctly. It is reloading each time I press the back button though?

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I think you should handle this in your application logic. If your router correctly handles the backbutton event and executes the binded method, then in that method you can change your views.

Comment: @nilgundag what do you mean?