# Backbone go to same route won't refresh the page

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a very simple  tag which will go the current route, since I need to refresh the page to clear some messages.

```
<span>Click <a href="/#resetPassword">here</a> to go get your password back</span>
```

<-- I am at /resetpassword route now -->

But this won't work, since I believe is Backbone route detects it is the same route, therefore just returns.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526752/backbone-refresh-the-same-route-path-for-twice) is related to mine, but there is a difference that I am not using functions, just  tag.

(CMD + R) works

So is there any way I can refresh the same route page in  tag?

Thanks!

Comment: catch the click event and navigate using backone and the trigger option?

Answer (score 0):

In the view I would do this.

In the view

```
events: 
  "click span": "resetPage"

resetPage: ->
  @trigger "reset:page"
```

Then in the controller

```
  @listenTo currentView, "reset:page", (args) ->
        model = args.model
        App.vent.trigger "reset:page", model
```

Then in your router you listen for that message and call your API route again, essentially refreshing the page, but if you have something you would need to re-fetch you could just pass that along with each message and avoid having the memory/unresponsive feeling that a `navigate({trigger: true})` would cause :).

```
@SampleApp.module "PostsApp", (PostsApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class PostsApp.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
      ""            : "list"
      ":id"         : "show"

  API =
    list: ->
      new PostsApp.List.Controller

    show: (id, post) ->
      new PostsApp.Show.Controller
        id: id
        post: post

  App.vent.on "posts:list:clicked", ->
    App.navigate "/"
    API.list()

  App.vent.on "reset:page", (post) ->
    App.navigate "/" + post.id
    API.show post.id, post

  App.addInitializer ->
    new PostsApp.Router
      controller: API
```

To avoid re-fetching the post you'd do this in the initialize function in your controller:

```
@SampleApp.module "PostsApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class Show.Controller extends App.Controllers.Application

    initialize: (options) ->
      { post, id } = options
      post or= App.request "post:entity", id

      App.execute "when:fetched", post, =>
        @layout = @getLayoutView()

        @listenTo @layout, "show", =>
          @panelRegion post
          @postRegion post
          @bannerRegion post

        @show @layout
```

That will keep your app very responsive - note this is assuming you don't need to reset your models/collections. If you need to just reset the model/collection data the `navigate({trigger: true})` route might be the way to go. Unless you want to keep track of say items you added and in the event do some manual resetting and then re-render the view.

I suppose you also could implement a `"resetModel"` function in your model that will re-fetch it and trigger a custom event which your view could listen to as a `modelEvents` and then re-render itself.