# Backbone router.navigate doesn't redirect

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

Honestly I feel a bit stupid asking this question because should be a very simple thing...
In my app init, I have:

```
window.myApp =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}
  initialize: ->
    window.router = new Backbone.Router

    Backbone.history.start(pushState: true)
```

And then in my View, when I click a button, I do:

```
router.navigate('/profile')
```

I have tried also with

```
router.navigate('/profile', true)
```

Now...I know that this isn't the best way of use backbone routes, but I need that my rails app manage the routes and I use backbone routes only for have routes history...
If I do window.href = '/profile' it redirects correctly.

What I'm doing wrong with backbone routes ? I've used this way time ago, but I don't find out why now it doesn't work anymore.

**EDIT: The new url is always correctly show in the navigation bar, but it doesn't redirect to the new page...only show the new url in the navigation bar.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Backbone router.navigate doesn't redirect

No, it doesn't. That's not what `router.navigate` even **does**. It's has nothing to do with redirecting, it's for updating the address bar.

> The new url is always correctly show in the navigation bar, but it doesn't redirect to the new page...only show the new url in the navigation bar.

Yes, this is **exactly** what `router.navigate` is documented to do. That is its express purpose. You use it to update the URL to reflect the current state of the page, **not** to redirect the page to something else.

If you want to redirect to a new page, you're supposed to use `window.location.href = '/profile'`.

If you want to update the address bar and then trigger a fresh round of Backbone routing, use `router.navigate('/profile', { trigger: true });`, but again, that's not how Backbone is meant to work.

Comment: Thank you...now I've understood better :)

Answer (score 0):

We had an issue with this, and found out that sometimes even **window.location.href** does not work.

We were lucky to find this post [Backbone: Refresh the same route path for twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526752/backbone-refresh-the-same-route-path-for-twice) and we were actually only able to make it work using a combination of the presented solution :

1. Navigate to an inexistent route : `Backbone.history.navigate('xpto');`
2. Then use: `window.location.href = location;`