# BackboneJs Browser refresh should load the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm new to backboneJs.

Currently when i do browser refresh, it takes back me to login page.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes : {
        // Pages           
        'startup' : 'LoginScreen',
        'Home' : 'HomeScreen',
        'AssetDetail':'AssetScreen',
        '*actions' : 'LoginScreen'
    },
    ...
   });



    var initialize = function(options) {
     var appView = options.appView;
     var router = new AppRouter(options);


router.on('route:LoginScreen', function(actions) {
    require([ 'login/LoginView' ], function(StartView) {
        console.log(" --route login");
        var startView = new StartView();
    });
});

router.on('route:HomeScreen', function(actions) {

    require([ 'home/HomeView' ], function(HomeScreenView) { 
     console.log(" --route home");

     var homeScreenView = new HomeScreenView();

 });
});

router.on('route:AssetDetailScreen', function(actions) {


    require([ 'views/AssetDetailView' ],    function(AssetDetailScreenView) {
        var assetdetailScreenView = new AssetDetailScreenView();

    });
});

Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

};

So lets say my current url is **http://localhost:8080/myapp/#**  , and when i do browser refresh (F5 may be) , I want to load the same page.

How do I do it ?, Help me!

Answer (score 1):

Not me who originally wrote this answer but I think it's the best solution.

*"You can call Backbone.history.loadUrl.
To refresh the current page:

```
*`Backbone.history.loadUrl(Backbone.history.fragment);`*
```

Or as a link handler:
// `Backbone.history.navigate` is sufficient for all Routers and will trigger the
// correct events. The Router's internal `navigate` method calls this anyways.

```
var ret = Backbone.history.navigate(href, true);
```

// Typically Backbone's history/router will do nothing when trying to load the same URL.
// But since we want it to re-fire the same route, we can detect 
// when Backbone.history.navigate did nothing, and force the route.

```
if (ret === undefined) {
    Backbone.history.loadUrl(href);
}"*
```

[Backbone: Refresh the same route path for twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526752/backbone-refresh-the-same-route-path-for-twice)