# Is there a way to trigger hashchange event even though the route is not changed in backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, hashchange

Iam using backbone in my project. In my web page, when I apply filters, my route will not change. That filter is added as an parameter to my query.

So my scenario is, even though my route does not change, I want hashchange event to be triggered. How can I do it in backbone.js?

Comment: Is this answering your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526752/backbone-refresh-the-same-route-path-for-twice

Comment: Yes, use `{trigger:true}` on the navigate method of your router http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate